# PHP Undefined Variable, but it's defined and has a value

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I am working on a PHP project - I had one form post a date to another form
I made some changes (although none to the input in question)
Now all other inputs are updated with their Posted values, except the date

If I manually set the date in HTML it works:

```
    <div><input type="date" class="form-control" id="DateCourse" name="DateCourse" value="2009-01-01"></div>
```

If I set it to the following, it doesn't:

```
    <div><input type="date" class="form-control" id="DateCourse" name="DateCourse" value="<?php echo (isset($DateCourse))?$DateCourse:'';?>"></div>
```

The below:

```
   $DateCourse = ($_POST["DateCourse"]);
   var_dump($_POST["DateCourse"]); 
   var_dump($DateCourse);
```

Returns:

string(10) "2019-01-05" - means the post value is set

Notice: Undefined variable: DateCourse in /home/bitecons/bts.biteconsulting.co.za/v2/editccr.php on line 119 - how can it be undefined, I just defined it

NULL

What on earth am I doing wrong? Apart from using PHP :P

Flow as requested:

Records.php:

This is the function to prepopulate my posted fields:

```
    function Prefill(x) {
      TabletoEdit = x.closest('table').id; 
      SelectedRow = x.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById("EntryEditing").value = x.cells[19].innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("DateCourse").value = x.cells[0].innerHTML;
      document.forms["records"].submit();
    }
```

Then I also have:

```
    <form action="editrec" method="post" id="records">
      <input type='hidden' name='Period' id='Period'  />
      <input type='hidden' name='Month' id='Month'  />
      <input type='hidden' name='res' id='res'  />
      <input type='hidden' name='CustName' id='CustName'  />
      <input type='hidden' name='DateCourse' id='DateCourse'  />
    </form>
```

The Prefill gets called, then submits the form

I have tracked and DateCourse has data, but when getting to the other form, it "disappears":

```
    if(!empty($_POST)) {
      $DateCourse = ($_POST["DateCourse"]);
      $CustName = ($_POST["CustName"]);
    }
```

For example, CustName is filled in, but not DateCourse?

Side question:

Would this return true if another post var is not set (unrelated to this one):

```
    if(!empty($_POST))
```

Comment: if both code on same page and u did not check submit button is set or not, then it will show undefined. so kindly show more code.

Comment: Does this file /home/bitecons/bts.biteconsulting.co.za/v2/editccr.php contains HTML part as listed in the question or HTML part is in different page?

Comment: Can you add the whole code? So that we can see the flow

Comment: At this stage the form has been submitted, the data is in the post. All other posted vars have updated the relevant inputs

Comment: The flow is basically this - User double clicks an entry on a table (records.php for example), this has many hidden html inputs that gets updated before being posted.. The action on the form on records.php opens up editrec.php. All inputs on editrec.php are populated, except for this date...

Comment: The full code is needed @CraigArcher because your further description as you state it could be introducing things that you dont see

Comment: - is $DateCourse variable defined before line 119 in this file : /home/bitecons/bts.biteconsulting.co.za/v2/editccr.php ?
- is the definition of $DateCourse variable inside if else clause ?

Answer (score 0):

I think  You use wrong Code 
you Must  Submit First Form And Then Use $DateCourse this In another Form in POSTBACK

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way is to define $DateCourse too like

```
<?php
$DateCourse = "";
if(!empty($_POST["DateCourse"])) {
    $DateCourse = ($_POST["DateCourse"]);
}
?>
<div><input type="date" class="form-control" id="DateCourse" name="DateCourse" value="<?php echo $DateCourse;?>"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have established that it's not empty. I tried your code regardless and still the same... You have helped though - if(!empty($_POST)) looks to be the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Okay, apologies folks, but it may help others in the future. 
I had a function call to an old function - this failed, causing my variable to never get defined... I knew it was something stupid, but sometimes one needs a sound board...